# Filter Dictionary<string, string> using LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` called `roleList`. In this case, `roleList` lists the role and the role right above that role in hierarchy - I need to preserve both key and value for the item matching the 'key' role and can discard the rest.

I also have access to a function previously written which will let me know if the user is in a specific role (or array of roles) (it returns only a boolean) but I can't tell what role is a user in because the user might hold several roles.

All the same, I need to know if the user is in a specific role.

Without iterating the dictionary with a `For Each`, I currently have:

```
roleList.Select(x => IsInRoles(userInfoObj,  new string[] {x.Key}) == true).ToList();
```

Note that `IsInRoles(params)` returns a boolean. Also note that `userInfoObj` is just a custom object that is defined elsewhere and I really don't have control over it.

The above statement always fails to filter out the ones where `IsInRoles` returns false. What ought I change?

Update: per comments, I have tried the plain `.Where` option and explicitly stating `...IsInRoles(...) == true`. It still fails to filter the list. I have also explicitly checked to see if higher roles include lower roles (they do not). To be explicit:

```
roleList.Where(x => IsInRoles(userInfoObj,  new string[] {x.Key}) == true).ToList();
```

and

```
roleList.Where(x => IsInRoles(userInfoObj,  new string[] {x.Key})).ToList();
```

both fail equally. That is to say that I have 4 items in the dictionary going in and 4 coming out. Testing `IsInRoles` explicitly works as I would expect, there is no problem with that function (we've been using it for years). The problem is that neither `where` nor `select` filter out the false results.

People keep wanting to know the IsInRoles method:

```
public static bool IsInRoles(CurrentUserInfo user, string[] roles, string siteName, bool hasAllRoles) {
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to use `Select`. You want to use [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: You mean `roleList.Where(r => isInRoles(userInfoObj, r.Key))`?

Comment: .Where("true statement") isn't filtering out the "false" results. Edit: hold on, I need to check role hierarchy to see if higher includes lowers... Will update.

Comment: Update: nope, they do not include lower roles and it's not filtering correctly.

Comment: Please post _exactly_ what you have now after switching to `Where`.  It _seems_ like that should work.

Comment: Also note that `Select` and `where` are doing essentially the same thing as `foreach` so there's not a huge difference there (other than a better syntax).

Comment: @DStanley: Yah, I know. I've put up the new `where` for you.

Comment: Please add exact signature of `IsInRoles`

Comment: Done. It's at the bottom of the edited question

Comment: Your `Where` syntax looks correct so the only logical answer is that `IsInRoles` is returning `true` for all key values in the dictionary.  Try changing it to a `foreach` loop and debugging it to get a better understanding of what the problem is.

Comment: Also, are you capturing the _result_ of `Where` or expecting it to filter `roleList` in-place?

Comment: I've done this exact .Select/.Where before and it works as you see it however explicitly trying to throw it into another dictionary causes compiler errors due to not being able to go from an enumerated generic object to a dictionary. Doing it inside a foreach works as expected. The goal is to not use a foreach because there are multiple groups of roles to iterate and the simpler the filter, the less code maintenance in the future since it would be identical code.

Comment: So you _are_ capturing the results in a list or something?  Can you show a little bit more code around it so it's clear how you're capturing the result and verifying that it's not what you expect?

Comment: No, the .select has worked in the past to filter out all the items that didn't match the condition in the select or where without explicitly saying `varObj = obj2.select(x=> somecondition).ToList()`. What you see (roelList.select(...).ToList()) is exactly how it's worked for me in the past. I've been trying to find the SO post where I found that but I'm failing right now. I was puzzled in the past when it worked because it didn't make sense to me... usually you need that equals sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Select` does not filter a collection.  It returns a *projection* of the original collection - either a new type or a transformation to a new value of the same type.  `Where` is used to filter a collection or projection.

However, you need to capture the *result* of `Where` to get the filtered values:

```
var roles = roleList.Where(x => IsInRoles(userInfoObj,  new string[] {x.Key}));
```

or

```
var roles = roleList.Where(x => IsInRoles(userInfoObj,  new string[] {x.Key}))
                    .ToList();
```

if you want to hydrate the results to a list.

You seem to think that you have seen it work without assigning it to a variable, but `Where` *returns* an iterator that filters the collection.  If you do not capture that return value then it gets lost.  It certainly does not filter the original collection in-place.

Comment: 31eee384 has a nice comment about *why* my thinking was the way it was and after looking and thinking, he's right. In any case, this has to be the solution with one addition: because it's going into a dictionary (not a list), it needs to end with `.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)` Thanks.

Comment: OK That makes sense.  Another reason why Linq with side-effects is a bad idea.  Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
var roles = roleList.Where(x => IsInRoles(userInfoObj,  new string[] {x.Key}))
                    .Select(r => r.Key).ToList();
```

`roles` is a list with the roles a user is in.

The `Select(r => r.Key)` take only the keys, that is, the roles you want to know.

The `ToList()` returns a list with the result filtered.

Comment: I think the key here is "The `ToList()` returns a list with the result filtered.". I suspect asker has seen some linq with side effects in the past, where ignoring the return value makes sense and `.ToList()` is just there to force the evaluation.

Comment: You hit that spot on. In the end, I'm using a lighter version of this using just a .where and then doing .ToDicitonary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve only the specified key and value of that key, just simply do this

```
string key = the 'key' role;
string val = roleList[temp1];    //save the key vand value
roleList.Clear ();               //clear all values
roleList.Add (key, val);         // add the key and value back
```

If you use Select (), since it is a function, you have to assign the result back to roleList (but still it isn't efficient)

```
roleList = roleList.Select(x => IsInRoles(userInfoObj,  new string[] {x.Key}) == true).ToList();
```

Comment: I can't use the first half of your suggestion because until the entire dictionary is "iterated", I have no idea which key and value to keep. The user might actually be in 5 roles, 3 of which belong to a specific role group and then I need to get the first one out of it because the dictionary is ordered in a top-down hierarchy. Additionally, .Select needs to end with .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value), not .ToList()

Comment: Then I think you should manually iterate the dictionary using `foreach`, that would be more efficient than using `Where`. And for my second code, I was mistaken, my apologies.